# Can I apply a WHERE clause if COUNT condition is met?

Tags: oracle, plsql, case, oracle-sqldeveloper, where-clause

I'm having a hard time trying to add a `WHERE` clause that filters `null` values from a column ONLY when there are other rows that return data for that same column.

If **all** rows have `null` values for that column, keep them all.

If **any** row has data for that column, remove the rows with null values and just keep the rows with data.

**I'm working on an Oracle database.**

In my SELECT statement, I'm currently using a `LEFT JOIN` to pull data from **table B** even if the values for column **B.info** are null.

The actual query goes as follows:

```sql
SELECT A.id as A_ID, A.name as A_NAME, 
B.id as B_ID, B.name as B_NAME, B.info as B_INFO
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.id = A.id_B
WHERE A.filename = 'file1.txt'
```

I have 2 possible scenarios in the bussiness I'm working on:

1. For a given "filename", the query returns some rows with the `B.info` column with null values and some others with the `B.info` column filled with data. I want the query to return **only** the rows with `B.info != null`.

**Scenario 1 - Actual output:**

```
+-------+--------+------+--------+-----------+
| A_ID  | A_NAME | B_ID | B_NAME | B_INFO    |
+-------+--------+------+--------+-----------+
| 1     | John   | null | null   | null      |
+-------+--------+------+--------+-----------+
| 2     | John   | 3    | Julia  | Age is 35 |
+-------+--------+------+--------+-----------+
| 3     | John   | null | null   | null      |
+-------+--------+------+--------+-----------+
```

**Scenario 1 - Desired output:**

```
+-------+--------+------+--------+-----------+
| A_ID  | A_NAME | B_ID | B_NAME | B_INFO    |
+-------+--------+------+--------+-----------+
| 2     | John   | 3    | Julia  | Age is 35 |
+-------+--------+------+--------+-----------+
```

2. For a given "filename", the query returns all of the rows with the `B.info` column with `null` values.
   I want the query to keep returning those rows.

**Scenario 2 - Actual output = desired output:**

```
+-------+--------+------+--------+--------+
| A_ID  | A_NAME | B_ID | B_NAME | B_INFO |
+-------+--------+------+--------+--------+
| 1     | Mark   | null | null   | null   |
+-------+--------+------+--------+--------+
| 2     | Mark   | null | null   | null   |
+-------+--------+------+--------+--------+
| 3     | Mark   | null | null   | null   |
+-------+--------+------+--------+--------+
```

I tried adding the condition `B.info is not null` in the where clause but, although it returns the desired output for the scenario 1, the output for the scenario 2 returns no rows:

```sql
SELECT A.id as A_ID, A.name as A_NAME, 
B.id as B_ID, B.name as B_NAME, B.info as B_INFO
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.id = A.id_B
WHERE A.filename = 'file1.txt' 
AND B.info is not null
```

**Scenario 1 - Output**

```
+-------+--------+------+--------+-----------+
| A_ID  | A_NAME | B_ID | B_NAME | B_INFO    |
+-------+--------+------+--------+-----------+
| 2     | John   | 3    | Julia  | Age is 35 |
+-------+--------+------+--------+-----------+
```

**Scenario 2 - Output**

```
+-------+--------+------+--------+--------+
| A_ID  | A_NAME | B_ID | B_NAME | B_INFO |
+-------+--------+------+--------+--------+
+-------+--------+------+--------+--------+
```

I also tried adding a CASE in the WHERE clause but it throws an error (`ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here`)

```sql
SELECT A.id as A_ID, A.name as A_NAME, 
B.id as B_ID, B.name as B_NAME, B.info as B_INFO
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.id = A.id_B
WHERE A.filename = 'file1.txt' 
AND B.info = CASE WHEN count(B.info) > 0 THEN null
    ELSE B.info
    END
```

I'm sorry I can't use the real example for confidentiality issues. I hope my example is clear enough. I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Count all rows and nullable rows. Use analytic count, because you need details. Then show only rows containing data or null rows if both counts are equal:

```
select id, a_name, b_name, info
  from (
    select a.id, b.id b_id, a.name a_name, b.name b_name, b.info, 
           count(case when b.id is null then 1 end) over (partition by a.filename) c1,
           count(1) over (partition by a.filename) c2
      from a left join b on a.id = b.id )
  where b_id is not null or c1 = c2
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e53053c6dd23da5774cc703411cd4b82)</sup>**

Answer (score 1):

You can consider this problem a ranking problem: You want to show the best rows only, with non-null rows being considered "better" than null rows.

Ranking can be achieved with an appropriate ORDER BY clause. As of Oracle 12c:

```
select
  a.id as a_id, a.name as a_name, 
  b.id as b_id, b.name as b_name, b.info as b_info
from a
left join b on b.id = a.id_b
where a.filename = 'file1.txt'
order by case when b.id is null then 2 else 1 end
fetch first rows with ties;
```

In older versions:

```
select a_id, a_name, b_id, b_name, b_info
from
(
  select
    a.id as a_id, a.name as a_name, 
    b.id as b_id, b.name as b_name, b.info as b_info,
    rank() over (order by case when b.id is null then 2 else 1 end) as rnk
  from a
  left join b on b.id = a.id_b
  where a.filename = 'file1.txt'
)
where rnk = 1;
```